# {"Only TimeSpan objects can be serialized by MySqlTimeSpan"} with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters, ado.net, timespan

I have form2 to add a new data in my table then I got this error :

```
 {"Only TimeSpan objects can be serialized by MySqlTimeSpan"}
```

when I removed this part of code it works:

```
 cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Time_Operation",  MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = Time_OperationTextBox.Text
    cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Start_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = Start_TimeTextBox.Text
    cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@End_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = End_TimeTextBox.Text
```

it means the datetime is working good but the problem with those three parameters which I made them as a

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=springdb;Uid=root;Pwd=2342"


    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)

        Dim query As String = "Insert Into springdata (full_name,rfid_tag,spring_size,operation_time,Date_Operation,
                                    Time_Operation,Start_Time,End_Time,Qty_Needed) values
                                    (@full_name, @rfid_tag, @spring_size, @operation_time,
                                    @Date_Operation, @Time_Operation, @Start_Time, @End_Time, @Qty_Needed) 
                                      " 'Note:TextBox3 is the RFID number come from RFID arduino

        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@full_name", MySqlDbType.LongText)).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@rfid_tag", MySqlDbType.LongText)).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@spring_size", MySqlDbType.MediumText)).Value = TextBox3.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@operation_time", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Date_Operation", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Time_Operation", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = Time_OperationTextBox.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Start_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = Start_TimeTextBox.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@End_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = End_TimeTextBox.Text
        cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Qty_Needed", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = TextBox7.Text


        con.Open()

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("success")
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: You're passing strings into the parameters, but saying they have other types. Have you tried converting to the types you say you are passing?

Comment: it's because the value in something like `Time_OperationTextBox.Text` is a **string** but your mySQL method expects a [**TimeSpan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) - you need to parse the string into a TimeSpan which you then pass into the mySQL parameter.

Comment: I am just confused where I can put the code to convert it!

Comment: Just wrap your text box reference in a call to TimeSpan.Parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling that you that what you're giving to the parameter value is of type `string`, but your mySQL method expects a `TimeSpan` - you need to *parse* the string entered into the textbox as a `TimeSpan`, and then pass the resulting TimeSpan variable into the mySQL parameter instead of the string.

The `TimeSpan.Parse()` method accepts a string as input, and then outputs a TimeSpan object using the values it reads from the string.

```
cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Time_Operation",  MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = TimeSpan.Parse(Time_OperationTextBox.Text)
cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Start_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = TimeSpan.Parse(Start_TimeTextBox.Text)
cm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@End_Time", MySqlDbType.Time)).Value = TimeSpan.Parse(End_TimeTextBox.Text)
```

Of course, before that you must ensure that what your users entered into the textboxes is in a valid format understood by the TimeSpan code (see documentation link below for info on accepted formats).

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks :) Now no errors about TimeSpan but the value in three textboxes not added in the database table! the 3 cells are empty!

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out in this way:

```
        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(("Insert Into springdata (full_name,rfid_tag,spring_size,operation_time,Date_Operation,
                                    Time_Operation,Start_Time,End_Time,Qty_Needed )  Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "',
                                    '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "',
                                     '" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "', '" & Time_OperationTextBox.Text & "', 
                                      '" & Start_TimeTextBox.Text & "', '" & End_TimeTextBox.Text & "', 
                                      '" & TextBox7.Text & "')"), con)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't solved it with `timespan,parse`  :-)

Comment: opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks (and potentially daft syntax errors) is not the way to solve the problem. What went wrong when you tried TimeSpan.parse? What format are you allowing people to enter into the time textbox? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2 tells you what formats are acceptable

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your suggestion...you are right! What I want from the user is to enter in the textbox for time like: `08:10:00` the same format in database table. but I couldn't figure it out how to do it with 'TimeSpan.parse`

Comment: Like I said, what exactly went wrong when you tried? What code did you write, exactly?

Comment: Actually I had time to add a full answer, for clarity

Comment: @ADyson please if you have time can make an answerbecause I am newbie :) I don't know how and where to put the code!. sorry for that

Comment: I already did, see my last comment. The answer should be visible to you already. P.S. It's just a simple call to a method - you put in your string, and you get a TimeSpan out. :-)